# When do we have $Na=Ma\cap N~?$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and  $N$ be an $R$-submodule of $M$.   For the element  $0\neq a\in R$, under what conditions can the following hold: 
 $$Na=Ma\cap N~?$$

I already know that $Na\subseteq Ma$ and $Na\subseteq N$ which implies that $Na\subseteq Ma\cap N$.  So I only require cases when $Ma\cap N\subseteq Na$.

Comment: Usually no, but yes when $N$ is a direct summand of $M$.

Comment: Or $a$ is invertible, for instance. (Perhaps need more restrictions on what kind of conditions you want to get a reasonable answer.)